# Vaadin CheckBox object becomes null

Tags: java, vaadin

I have this Vaadin object:

```
CheckBox mycb = new CheckBox("caption");
```

Later on the **value** of this checkbox is updated from the database like this:

```
mycb.setValue(dbvalue);
```

`dbvalue` is actually NULL in the database. `mycb` was **not null** before this line, and is **null** after this line. Shouldn't its value remain the same, only `mycb.getValue()` returning null?

Furthermore, trying to avoid a NullPointerException with short-circuit evaluation:

```
if (mycb != null && mycb.getValue() == true) 
...
```

That produces a NullPointerException anyway. Is this normal behavior or there is something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The only way mycb becomes null after calling setValue is if that method somehow (down the line) accesses the same mycb variable. Maybe there is some event listener that listens and has the statement mycb = null? Is mycb a local variable?

Comment: Did u add any listeners to mycb, especially ValueChangeListener ?

Comment: @DavidtenHove, mycb is a field, and I tried with 'private' and 'final' and the result is the same.

Comment: @kukis, yes, there is a listener that checks its value with .getValue()

Comment: If the field is final, it is completely impossible for it to be null after succesfully calling a method on it. Are you SURE mycb == null after the method call? If so, please show how you verified it

Comment: You need show us more code :) Otherwise it makes no sense

Comment: @DavidtenHove It looks like it's not really null: I was verifying it with println, which calls the toString method and this method shows the value of the ComboBox, and that value is 'null'. But I still get a NullPointerException when doing mycb.getValue() !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said yourself mycb doesn't actually become null. That's great.

```
if (mycb != null && mycb.getValue() == true)
```

This throws a `NullPointerException` because Java tries to cast the result of `mycb.getValue()` to a `boolean`. But because `mycb.getValue()` returns `null`, it throws a `NullPointerException`.

Change it to:

```
if (mycb.getValue() != null && mycb.getValue() == true)
```

Or something similar

Comment: It works. Conclusion: it had nothing to do with Vaadin in the end, in Java just doing "Boolean b = null; if (b);" you get a NPE ;)